# Why is Javascript number type being changed to string?

Tags: javascript

I'm producing an AJAX generated list, there's a "load more" button that should increment the counter by 8 each time

The code for the button is `<button data-pointer="8"></button>`. The Javascript that runs the AJAX call send this value through the call;

```
 var pointer = $(this).attr('data-pointer');
 send AjaxRequest(..., pointer, ...);
 pointer += 8;
 $(this).attr('data-pointer', pointer);
```

The call works fine but my pointer value is now `88`

NB: I need to use `attr('data-pointer')` rather than `data('pointer')` as it appears that this is the only way to set this attribute dynamically.

I don't understand why, my understanding is that Javascript is dynamically typed and should interpret the addition `+=8` as `16`

Where am I going wrong and how do I ensure the variable is typed correctly?

Comment: "*my understanding is that Javascript is dynamically typed*" - yes, and DOM attributes are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bergi pointed out in the comments, the `data-pointer` attribute on your element is a string, not a number. Just convert it to a number first:

```js
$('#ex').click(function() {
  let pointer = parseInt($(this).attr('data-pointer'));
  $(this).attr('data-pointer', pointer + 8);
  
  console.log($(this).attr('data-pointer'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ex" data-pointer="8">Click to console.log data-pointer attribute</div>
```